# Android ScrollView...spacing between items in linearLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I've got a working ScrollView/LinearLayout that I'm using to display guitar chords, but the scroller has them spaced apart about one inch apart.  Can't find a setting to close up the 2500 or so items I'm scrolling.

I won't post code, mostly because it's working, but unable to find the setting or approach that will let me close them up tighter.  Most posts like this are complaining about no spacing, and I'm opposite:  I need LESS space between text...

I've got 3 columns in the LinearLayout so I can cram more chords in there so folks can click them quicker :)

Thx for any 'stupid noob' assistance.  I'm one week into this and it's a hoot.

Comment: Code is always helpful because its hard to figure out the issue unless we can see what your doing. Otherwise its all just educated guesses. So post any code if possible. But I will give a guess, have you looked at the padding, margin, height, etc and made sure those are not the cause?

Answer (score 3):

The setting I needed was in the XML, not in the Design.  I set all the

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp", and that's about right for what I need.
```

I just answered my own question!  Yay.